# ImageView ScaleType.FIT_XY not working with setImageDrawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, scaletype

I need to copy an ImageView in my application and change it's size whenever the user wants. What I do is here:

```
public void testClick(View view)
{
    ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
    im.setImageDrawable(((ImageView) view).getDrawable());
    Point size = getSize();//size of the window
    al.addView(im, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), size.x / 2, size.y / 2));
    im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    im.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}
public void changeSize()
{
   ...
   view.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width + deltaX, height + deltaY, params.x, params.y));
}
```

It doesn't work! means when I increase the size of the view, the image inside is not stretched.
But the weird thing happens when I change the line `im.setImageDrawable(((ImageView) view).getDrawable());` with `im.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);`
It works!
any idea?

I do not want to use `setImageResource` because I need to copy the drawable of the clicked view, not a static one from resources.

**Edit: When I use it in Galaxy Note 6.(I think it is Android 5) it works. but on my Android 4.1.2 device, it doesn't!**

---

**Edit2: I used**

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
im.setImageBitmap(bd.getBitmap());
```

**and it workd!**

Comment: try calling view.invalidate() after changing size.

Comment: @DavidH it didn't work

Comment: another thing you could try would be using setImageBitmap() in place of setImageDrawable(), as I believe setImageResource() is deprecated.

Comment: @DavidH I use setImageDrawable because I want to copy the content of the source ImageView and it is available only in Drawable.
And I do not think setImageResource is deprecated because Android Studio has not told me anything...

Comment: Oh yeah, it's not deprecated but see this quote from android docs for setImageResource() "This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead."

Comment: @DavidH didn't solve this problem, but was a very useful information anyway :)

Comment: @DavidH your comment on using setImageDrawable did work! I think drawable object is immutable and because of this, it didn't work.

Comment: Oh that's cool! Good to know you've managed to solve it.

Comment: You can mutate drawable by using getDrawable().mutate(). That was was my first suggestion but I deleted it. You could also try it without using setImageBitmap() if you're looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't! it's really strange. Also, you can post your answer so that i can mark it answerd if you want.

Comment: It's alright. All I've been doing is mostly just suggestions and not a sure solution. Anyway, I'm  glad that it finally works. It really is a strange case, tbh. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, use below code to change your `ImageView` size

```
mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = myWidth;
mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = myHeight;
```

And then call

```
mImageView.requestLayout();
```

to have the size change take effect.

I believe this should solve your problem.

Comment: it didn't! actually, event without re-sizing, my code doesn't work. But it is supposed to. because i use a big size to add it to the AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: @Feri at this point, it'll help to know if you're using a custom Drawable class or anything that you haven't included in the post, but might be related.

Comment: no!all of the related stuff are included! You know, it copies the current drawable in the source ImageView(if it is scaled, it copies exactly the scaled image) But after that there is no change.

Comment: @Feri That means the simplest solution could be using mutate() while getting the Drawable like so- im.setImageDrawable((ImageView)view.getDrawable().mutate()). You could use this without the setImageBitmap()